# Difference in transit time for the Sun

Tags: python, sun, pyephem

Executing this code fragment:

```
import ephem
oma=ephem.Observer()
oma.lat='50.7975189'
oma.lon='4.3579155'
oma.elevation=114.43
oma.epoch=ephem.now()
sun=ephem.Sun(oma)
print "object transit time: ",sun.transit_time
print "observer next transit time: ", oma.next_transit(sun)
```

This gives the following output:

```
object transit time:  2012/9/5 11:41:03
observer next transit time:  2012/9/5 11:41:06
```

So there is a difference between of 3 seconds between the time of the Sun object en the time calculated for the observer of the Sun. Which of the two is the most reliable? If we compare these values with the local calculated values the observer next transit time is the closest.

If we do the same calculation for the Mars:

```
import ephem
oma=ephem.Observer()
oma.lat='50.7975189'
oma.lon='4.3579155'
oma.elevation=114.43
oma.epoch=ephem.now()
mars=ephem.Mars(oma)
print "object transit time: ",mars.transit_time
print "observer next transit time: ", oma.next_transit(mars)
```

This gives the following output:

```
object transit time:  2012/9/5 15:05:32
observer next transit time:  2012/9/5 15:05:32
```

So no difference.

Best regards,

Marble

Answer (score 1):

To determine which function is most accurate, simply feed the two times that they give you into the observer's `compute()` function and see which lands closest to the real moment of transit when the azimuth is exactly 180°:

```
import ephem
oma = ephem.Observer()
oma.lat, oma.lon = '50.7975189', '4.3579155'
oma.elevation = 114.43
sun = ephem.Sun()
for t in ('2012/9/5 11:41:03',
          '2012/9/5 11:41:06'):
    oma.date = t
    sun.compute(oma)
    print 'azimuth at', t, 'was', sun.az
```

The output from this script shows that the `11:41:06` time from the newer `next_transit()` function gives the more accurate result:

```
azimuth at 2012/9/5 11:41:03 was 179:58:45.4
azimuth at 2012/9/5 11:41:06 was 179:59:49.5
```

The lower accuracy of the old `.transit_time` attribute is why the current PyEphem documentation recommends always using `next_transit()` for all transit calculations for which it works. (Which means everything but earth satellites, for which `.transit_time` switches to a different algorithm anyway.)

In fact, the current documentation does not even mention that asking for the `.next_transit` of a non-earth-satellite is even possible, and the attribute is only there for ancient backwards compatibility.

Both functions work in the same way: by guessing a time, checking the azimuth at that time, and then refining their guess over and over until they like the answer. The more recent `next_transit()` function does this much better, so you should use it.

The reason that the two functions gave you the same answer for Mars is just coincidence — if you will run the functions against Mars for other dates than September 5th, you will see different answers come out. It all depends on the order in which the functions make their series of guesses, and whether the last guesses happen to land close together or far apart. And, I will bet that their answers did not *really* match even for September 5th — they merely matched down to the second, which was all that got displayed! If you were to display the full-precision Julian Date for those two answers by printing the `repr(float(…))` of each answer, then you will doubtless find disagreement way down beneath the decimal point beyond what a resolution of one second was able to show you.

Does that cover all of your concerns?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the transit_time does not goes for the observer.

I improved and  changed your code :

```
from ephem import Observer, Sun, now
oma=Observer()
oma.lat='50.7975189'
oma.lon='40.3579155'
oma.elevation=114.43
oma.epoch=now()
sun=Sun(oma)
print "object transit time: ",sun.transit_time
print "observer next transit time: ", oma.next_transit(sun)
```

and this gives :

```
object transit time:  2012/9/6 09:16:48
observer next transit time:  2012/9/7 09:16:27
```

Now, why is there one day diff (or -11 secs) for changing the lon from 4 to 40 ?
In what units are those lon and lat expressed in ephem ? Not part of this question, I suppose.